# Duplicate SQL database locally in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to find the best way to duplicate an existing database locally into my Visual Studio C# project (so I can work anywhere just by changing connection string).
The idea is to import all structure & procedure then delete some data.

But I'm not sure what is the best practice for doing it and procedure for doing it.
creating SQL project?

Adding Entity Framework reference?.

Found way to build base easily need postscript now.
ADD SQL project 
[image]
import structure from production database
[image]
Then deploy into localdatabase (now need check how i can have post script insert a chunk of data).

for the data i made it simple for now   i find no clean way  to do it without paid SSMS plugin (query to insert statement).
so made a 2 line of code with both instance source/taget.

```
 Entities source = new Entities();
           Entities1 target = new Entities1();
            var chunkA = source.Table1.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Take(50000);
            target.Table1.AddRange(chunkA);
            var chunkB = source.Table2.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).Take(50000);
            target.Table2.AddRange(chunkB);
```

Comment: Using SSMS, creating a backup and then restoring it locally? If this is a one time need I can't see any problem using dedicated tools for the job

Comment: i'm prety sure visual studio have all the procedure integrated why i tell "best practice"     it have sql express and can import structure/data itself just bit lost on how to do it

Comment: Create a database project, import source database schema, add scripts to insert data. Later deploy the project to an sql-server instance of choice.

Comment: yes    @Serg its what just did  local db structure is done now main problem     is how to fill table with only a chunk of data (not million rows) migth look into ssms generate script or project deploy  postscript  or code it in c# don't know (i have no skill in post script) i would slect top(10000) foreach table in it. if you can help with post script and sql cmd how it work

Comment: It's rather data specific task. Probably use a localdb as a portable storage or xml as well.

Answer (score -1):

Usually we do it using [Microsoft SQL Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

You can create queries you want starting from an existing database (table creation, table updates ecc..)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) you can find a guide to copy an entire database